# lxml etree iteration inside xpath searches

Tags: python, iteration, lxml

I've been trying to retrieve information from tree nodes. I got the nodes from xpath searches but inside those nodes I try to run xpath searches again but it goes to the root. Is it possible to iterate over nodes with specific classes and retrieve different information indide them?

The example of the code I'm parsing

```
<li>
    <div class="product-preview">
        <div class="product-image">
        <div class="product-info">
<\li>
```

I need to find those product-preview nodes that I'm already getting using

```
lxml.html.xpath( //div[contains(@class, product-preview)])
```

but when I try to get the different subnodes iterating over the results from the previous code, always searches in the parent

What I am trying to do is

```
for element in lxml.html.xpath( //div[contains(@class, product-preview)] ):
    element.xpath( "new search" )
```

How should I iterate over the elements to make new searches inside them?

Thank you very much.

Answer (score 0):

I've resolved the issue using the method find_class from lxml.html, it returns the node without parent. After that I can use xpath to search inside it.

```
for element in tree.find_class( class_name ):
    element.xpath( xpath ).get( attrib )
```